# Generate asp-core specific html code including asp-attributes

Tags: c#, html, razor, asp.net-core, reflection

I'm new to Razor but experienced in classic html and C#.

For the beginning I have done the [razor tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/aspnet/core/tutorials/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-2.2) from Microsoft. After doing it I wanted to play with the code and so I got my question.

I want to make the view-code more dynamic by creating the html by reflection ([this view-code I mean](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/aspnet/core/tutorials/razor-pages/page?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio#the-create-razor-page)). In future I want to generate whole html-forms by a model without the need to write html.

There are property blocks like this two examples (Title and Release Date):

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="Movie.Title" class="control-label"></label>
    <input asp-for="Movie.Title" class="form-control" />
    <span asp-validation-for="Movie.Title" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="Movie.ReleaseDate" class="control-label"></label>
    <input asp-for="Movie.ReleaseDate" class="form-control" />
    <span asp-validation-for="Movie.ReleaseDate" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
```

It is easy in C# to read that properties by reflection and create the html. But when I create the html I could not use the special "**asp-for**" and "**asp-validation-for**" attributes.

For testing if the server-side rendering supports the special "asp"-attributes I created the hardcoded (experimental) code below:

```html
@Html.Raw("<div class=\"form-group\">")
@Html.Raw("<label asp-for=\"Movie.Title\" class=\"control-label\"></label>")
@Html.Raw("<input asp-for=\"Movie.Title\" class=\"form-control\" />")
@Html.Raw("<span asp-validation-for=\"Movie.Title\" class=\"text-danger\"></span>")
@Html.Raw("</div>")
```

As I expected is the validation for "Title" no longer working.

My questions are:

- How generate by reflection asp-forms 
  (or at least is there a Html.Raw pendant for such a purpose?)
- How does the "asp"-attributes work in the background
  (is the compiler doing the magic or the runtime?)

Thanks for your effort!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`asp-*` are TagHelpers and are well documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/authoring?view=aspnetcore-2.2) It also shows you how to create your own.

I'd like to give a tip on how to think about Razor pages syntax. It's a template engine, so it takes in a `.cshtml` page, the extension is what tells dotnet core that it's a razor file. And spits out an html page which is then finally sent in the response to the client's browser (If you are looking for dynamically updating the page on the client side Razor cannot achieve this, it can only create the pages dynamically server side.).

So what does dotnet core do with the `asp-for` tag? Well it generates html attributes on the html element, `<input asp-for="Model.Prop" />` will turn into something like  `<input id="Prop" name="Prop" data-required="" data-maxlength="100" etc... />`

So you can create a custom attribute bind it to `<form curstom-attr-bind-model="MyModel"></form>`

And then when the page is requested the html page will be constructed on the server side, with your implementation for a generic form.

**Edit 1**

I cannot tell you how to do it via a custom attribute (yet, this got me interested I will figure it out atm I am looking how they implement their tag helpers [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/tree/a6199bbfbab05583f987bae322fb04566841aaea/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers) specifically for the `select` and `input` elements), however short term you could potentially do something like this:

Steps to take:

1. Write this: `<input asp-for="Form.Number" />` / `<span asp-validation-for="Form.Number"></span>`
2. Look in the browser what html is generated.
3. Mimic it with `Html.Raw()` method, will give you something along the lines of: `@Html.Raw("<input id=\"Form_Number\" name=\"Form.Number\" />")`

Why does it not work when you do it your way? Because it will step through you cshtml file line by line and execute any C# code to template out your html. once it executes `@Html.Raw()` it renders the text, if you take notice `asp-for="Model.Number"`, `Model.Number` isn't text but rather an object, even then it doesn't recreate the cshtml file recursively to keep looking for razor syntax until it's done. Hope this wasn't confusing, just think the cshtml to html process starts at the top of the file and then step by step follows the instructions until it reaches the end, and it should make sense.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. Now I know how the asp-attributes are working. The point how to create a custom attribute is good to know, thank you.

Did you know how I can use the default "asp-for"-attribute in a generated html doc? Like in the example in my first post with the five "@Html.Raw" calls?

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer!